# Two for loops, big O theory

Tags: c++, complexity-theory, big-o

I have this loop running inside a program:

```
for(int I =0;I < n;I++){
   for(int it = 0; it < m; it++){

       Access vector.at(it+1) & add number plus vector.at(it)
        }
  }
```

Both n & m are user input and what I want to do is run the inside loop the size of the vector (m) and store information. The outside loop is saying to repeat that process n times. 
So would my big O notation be O(m^n) since I'm repeating m however many times n is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing 2 operations in the inside loop, thus you are doing a total of 2 * n * m operations, which gives a O(n*m) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It would actually be `O(M x N)`

`O(M^N)` is very very slow :)

Comment: Ok thanks! I knew it was really slow and was unsure that m^n was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is O(*mn*), assuming that the operation inside the inner loop is O(1).

Comment: Thank you. Operation is constant time.